# How to invoke a DLL method from PowerShell 1.0

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I am using a PowerShell version 1.0 script to call a method from a DLL file and used the following code to load the DLL file into PowerShell.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("path of dll") is loaded successfully

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v2.0.50727     location of dll
```

The class contains a public default constructor. I tried to create an object of the class using the below code:

```
$obj = new-object namespce.classname
```

And it throws the following error:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'namespce.classname' threw an exception." 
>   At line:1 char:18 
>   + $obj = new-object <<<<  namespce.classname 
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException 
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

When I tried to call the method of the class without creating the object, it throws the below error even though the class contains the method:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> [namespace.classname]::method()
Method invocation failed because [namespace.classname] doesn't contain a method named 'method'.
At line:1 char:39
+ [namespace.classname]::method <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (method:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

It's a version error typically a DLL version issue. Dot NET does not allow for unloading and same for powershell. So, reboot will start over, and fix too. Just avoid the same issue by insuring no ambiguity of versions.

Comment: For that to success, method() will need to be static. Can you post the signature of the relevant method?, e.g. public static string foo(int bar){}

Comment: Hi MathewMartin,                                                          its public method() with return type is void.                                                                        public void method()

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the method is an instance method which means you will need to have an instance of the class. You can get that via a public default constructor on the class e.g.:

```
$obj = new-object namespace.classname
$obj.Method()
```

Perhaps the only public consctructor's require parameters e.g.:

```
$obj = new-object namespace.classname -arg 'string_arg',7
$obj.Method()
```

Or maybe there are no public constructors but there is a static Create or Parse method that returns an instance e.g.:

```
$obj = [namespace.classname]::Create()
$obj.Method()
```

Comment: Hi Keith Hill, 

Actually i tried the above method to create object and if a public default constructor, so i tried to create a object using the following code $obj = new-object namespace.classname  and it throwed the below error. 

` New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'classname.method' threw a
n exception."
At line:1 char:18
+ $obj = new-object <<<<  classname.method`

Comment: Type initializer is the static constructor. If that is failing it is likely the case that the assembly you loaded requires a type from another assembly that you haven't loaded. Use either ILDasm (comes with .NET SDK) or grab a free tool like dotPeek to open the assembly and see what other assemblies it references.  You will need to load the ones that aren't already loaded into the PowerShell process.