# Methods in reflected DLLs unable to be called. How can I get a better error message?

Tags: c#, powershell, reflection

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that will call a series of static methods in a static class (`MyClass`) contained within certain DLL (`MyNamespace.MyLibrary.dll`) through reflection.  However, even calling the simplest of methods (`MyNamespace.MyLibrary.MyClass.CallMe()`) inside that library fails with the following error message:

```
Exception calling "CallMe" with "0" argument(s): "The type initializer for 'MyNamespace.MyLibrary.MyClass' threw an exception."
At C:\temp\powershellTest.ps1:41 char:1
+ $output = [MyNamespace.MyLibrary.MyClass...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeInitializationException
```

The first odd thing is that I'm getting a type initialization (constructor?) error when trying to call a *static* method in a *static* class.

The PowerShell code making the call:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadFile($dllLocation + 'MyNamespace.MyLibrary.dll')
$output = [MyNamespace.MyLibrary.MyClass]::CallMe()
Write-Host $output
```

The relevant C# code:

```
namespace MyNamespace.MyLibrary
{
    public static class MyClass
    {
        public static string CallMe() // the CallMe() method was added just to try to debug this
        {
            return "I was called";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this particular library is much larger and has many dependencies, all used within other methods in `MyClass`.  I made another DLL that is literally as simple as can be (no external dependencies) to test my powershell reflection, and it succeeds in calling a static class' method (also static, obviously).  This tells me that my powershell is correct, so I looked up why I might be getting this issue.   [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152517/how-to-invoke-a-dll-method-from-powershell-1-0#comment26628813_18165909) says that it may not be automatically loading all of `MyNamespace.MyLibrary`'s references.

I tried two things to remedy that:

1. I copied all non-GACed DLLs referenced by `MyLibrary` into the same folder so they'd be side-by-side with MyLibrary.dll
2. When that didn't work, I also added explicit `[reflection.assembly]::LoadFile(path\otherAssembly.dll)` lines after the one for `MyNamespace.MyLibrary.dll` to make sure powershell could load them.  This also didn't work.

**Here's my main question:** How can I get a more specific error message about *which* dependency isn't being found and possibly where it's looking?  I was shocked when Attempted Fix #1 wasn't enough, and I'm not sure what else I can do.

I hope that made sense; feel free to ask any necessary clarifying questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you exception details:

```
try
{
  [reflection.assembly]::LoadFile($dllLocation + 'MyNamespace.MyLibrary.dll')
  $output = [MyNamespace.MyLibrary.MyClass]::CallMe()
  Write-Host $output
}
catch [Exception]
{
  echo $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message
}
```

---

Comment: Nothing useful: `System.TypeInitializationException
The type initializer for 'MyNamespace.MyLibrary.MyClass' threw an exception.`  Is there some way to see _what_ the exception thrown was?

Answer (score 1):

[According  to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914080/powershell-dll-loading) Run script from location that your dlls are copied and try this code:

```
$currentScriptDirectory = Get-Location
[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($currentScriptDirectory.Path)
```

Comment: No dice.  This doesn't appear to be doing anything different. In the answer you linked, they're at least getting the name of the missing DLL as part of the error message.  I don't even have that, and I'm trying to figure out why not.

Comment: The difference that makes sence is when you set current directory, assembly.LoadFile tries to load other refs from the current directory.

Comment: in catch block, use $_.Exception.InnerException.Message according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795751/can-i-get-detailed-exception-stacktrace-in-powershell). InnerException property of the TypeInitializationException contains information about the problem, and where it occurred.